# How to deploy an API that uses Sucrase with Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I'm using Sucrase to not use the CommonJS syntax of import. So to do that, I have installed the sucrase dependency and the Nodemon configure is set to register sucrase after Node runs every file.

That my Nodemon config:

```
{
  "execMap": {
    "js": "node -r sucrase/register"
  }
}
```

But the problem is that it just runs on development and I'm not finding a solution to run the app with the Procfile

```
web: node ./src/server.js & node ./src/queue.js
```

Heroku error logs:

```
2019-11-10T01:59:01.073862+00:00 app[web.1]: import Bee from 'beequeue';
2019-11-10T01:59:01.073864+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^
2019-11-10T01:59:01.073866+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-11-10T01:59:01.073867+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: u have syntax error `import Bee from 'beequeue';` use `const Bee = require( 'beequeue')`

Comment: yes, i know and that's because i'm using sucrase

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `nodemon` on Heroku (it's only for development) and indeed your `Procfile` shows that you're using `node` instead. Therefore your `nodemon` config isn't being used. [Sucrase isn't for production use, either](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sucrase): "You should think carefully before using Sucrase in production. Sucrase is mostly beneficial in development, and in many cases, Babel or tsc will be more suitable for production builds." Add a proper build step to your production build pipeline using Babel or tsc as the Sucrase README itself suggests.

Comment: i just solved the problem, but thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sucrase's just for development**, and behind the scenes it needs to convert the imports to the **common js sintax**. So to deploy your app, you can first run the **build command provided in the Sucrase Docs**, and then change the command of your procfile.

To generate the build, run this command:

```
 sucrase ./src -d /build --transforms javascript,imports
```

If you're using Typescript:

```
 sucrase ./src -d /build --transforms typescript,imports
```

and then, in your procfile:

```
web: node ./build/server.js & node ./build/queue.js
```

- But is not recommended to deploy on heroku because of the dyno, you can work with these builds in your server and a ci service like travis ci, circle ci or buddy that has a nice interface and you don't to do a lot of configurations.

Comment: Note that this isn't something you should be doing manually on Heroku. The built files will disappear whenever your dyno restarts, which happens very frequently. Add it to your build process so the compiled files are included in your application slug.